# How can i display a long string (paragraphs) in a label widget on multiple lines with a y scrollbar? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey im trying to put text that contains a few paragraphs in a label widget. I would like it to display on multiple lines and use a y scrollbar so everything can fit and be viewed in the label widget.

It should turn out like this:
[Except instead of a text widget it would be a label widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcME3.png)

I have tried to do this with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

writtenSolution = Tk()
writtenSolution.title("Written Response Question")
writtenSolution.resizable(0,0)

header = LabelFrame(writtenSolution, bg="white")
content = LabelFrame(writtenSolution, bg="white")

header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Forces column to expand to fill all available space
homeButton=Button(content,width=50,height=50)
try:
    homeIcon=PhotoImage(file="yes.png")
    homeButton.config(image=homeIcon)
    homeButton.image = homeIcon
except TclError:
    print("Home")
homeButton.grid(row=1, sticky="w", padx=15, pady=2)

titleHeader = Label(content, text="Solution Image here",pady=15, padx=20, bg="white", font=("Ariel",20, "bold"), anchor="w", relief="solid", borderwidth=1)
titleHeader.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=15, pady=5, ipadx=400, ipady=150)

text=str("CRXdJdRpVPJKzs2HZ 5YadBSDgsmMrWb OTsTkHoy23ygHrryEwNGvkabnM3UOJnM0PVvVU6KiXtDbvljdILbfwko1 R3dKSz6iTbKQHlHYqtFMB4xBclX5Jgc9Q8ThoXX292SO8JzWxaLq6jyfXItZx4g2 JQtAOaEtc4jSx643aLaqeRdyoqqvT1mzsrE5pa8EXMozajbRp5DvGpVanvym1BZFcdLmZEu1ykHgAGL4luFQYdoHTJ033Q3Btuu4oqRdAo4zAdPWVKOLGd316w7Os3H26eB2qQXxyMOfgzMWjWZD")

#the label widget is below:

answerInput = Label(content, borderwidth=2, font=("HelvLight", 18), height=10, width=60, text=text, relief="solid", bg="white")
answerInput.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w", padx=(20,0), pady=20)
#answerScrollBar= Scrollbar(content, command=answerInput.yview) #command code sets the scrollbars function so it can scroll vertically
#answerInput.configure(yscrollcommand=answerScrollBar.set)
#answerScrollBar.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ns", pady=20)

nextButton = Button(content, borderwidth=1, font=("Ariel", 22), text=("Next"+"\n"+"Question"), bg="#12a8e3", fg="black", activebackground="#12a8e3", relief="solid")
nextButton.grid(row=3, column=2, ipady=50, ipadx=70, sticky="nw", pady=20, padx=5)

header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')

writtenSolution.mainloop()
```

the string is stored in the text variable

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I think its way easier to put the text in another Text widget and make the state of it disabled or readonly (not sure how its calld atm). Thats why I'm asking you.

Comment: @Atlas435 Im trying to do a thing where the user enters some text and on the next page (this page) it displays that text.

Comment: @Atlas435 if i do this disable thing can i still display the text and not allow them to type or edit?

Comment: that's exactly what it used to be.

Comment: You can't do it with a label widget. A label widget doesn't support scrolling. You should use a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to copy and paste your text in another with the *state disabled*.

> To make the widget read-only, you can change the state option from
> NORMAL to DISABLED:

```
     text.config(state=NORMAL)
     text.delete(1.0, END)
     text.insert(END, text)
     text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

> Note that you must change the state back to NORMAL before you can
> modify the widget contents from within the program. Otherwise, calls
> to insert and delete will be silently ignored.

[more](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns)

to show you an executable example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_it(event):
    text = write_me.get('1.0','end') #get the text
    write_me.delete('1.0','end') #delet the text
    write_me.index('insert')
    
    show_me.config(state='normal')
    show_me.insert('end', text)
    show_me.config(state='disabled')

write_me = tk.Text(root)
write_me.pack(side='left')
write_me.bind('<Return>', show_it)

show_me = tk.Text(root,state='disabled')
show_me.pack(side='right')

root.mailoop()
```

Also note you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658025/13629335) to simplify it some more:

```
show_me = tkst.ScrolledText(root,state='disabled') #if you have python 3.7+
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to do what i need. But is there any way to add a string stored in a variable into the text box? I ask because the text that is gonna be displayed comes from a text box in another window/function so I dont think i can copy and paste it

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if I was getting it right. Also I think binding the return that actually is a default binding by the text widget itself isnt a good way. But I would show you something you can play with.

Comment: thanks this is what i need but when i try to add in a variable that holds a string into the text box nothing appears.

Comment: Hmm as you can see I just made it with `show_me.insert('end', text)` so this would be another question. You can write me the link here and I will look over it as soon as I'm on a machine.

Comment: Before asking you can try some basic debugging methods. Print your variable and if it's printed out in the shell then try print(type(variable)) and it must be string class, otherwise you need to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way you can do this.Make it as label and put `\n` to enter the line

```
from tkinter import *
my_window = tk.Tk()

label_1 = Label(my_window, text="Line of Text\nSecond Line of Text\nThird line of text",font="Times 14"
label_1.pack()

my_window.mainloop()
```

please upvote If it work's